# Quel serait l'antonyme d'« identiqueter » (to tag pictures) ?

Tags: préfixes, néologismes, antonyme

En ce qui a trait à l'action d' « établir l'identité d'une personne sur une photographie, généralement en associant à son visage une étiquette d'identification », on (A.-A. Provencal, J. Verge, OQLF) a créé le mot-valise [*identiqueter*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26543576), à partit des verbes *identifier* et *étiqueter* (GDT). Et j'aurais bien aimé le voir créé avant, à l'époque où je fréquentais un réseau social bien connu, avant l'introduction de la [frise chronologique](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8869294) (*timeline*), et que je demandais à tous mes « amis » de justement ne pas faire ça avec les photos sur lesquelles j'apparaissais (« ne me *tagguez* pas » : *to tag*)... et quand c'était fait bien je demandais qu'on [verbe] le *tag*...

---

- Comment aimerait-on former l'antonyme du néologisme *identiqueter* :
  peut-on expliquer pourquoi on préférerait le préfixer et comment ou
  pourquoi préférerait-on utiliser un verbe avec sa substantivation et
  si oui lequel ; peut-on présenter le tout dans une phrase complète
  (contenant le complément *photographie(s)/photos* au besoin) ?

Comment: En miroir à _identiqueter_, pourquoi pas _anonyqueter_?

Answer (score 1):

On peut rester dans la sphère des néologismes, supprimer l’identité c’est ***[anonymiser](http://[https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/anonymise][1])***.

Answer (score 1):

Je ne pense pas qu'on ait besoin d'un antonyme spécifique à ce mot. On peut utiliser "*supprimer*" :

> je demandais qu'on **supprime** le tag

On peut aussi cherché du côté du préfixe *dé-*. En France on utilisait pas mal le terme "*identifié*" :

> Facebook : Un ami vous a **identifié** sur une de ses photos [l'horreur !]

À l'époque, on utilisait des phrases comme :

> Salut, tu peux me **désidentifier** sur les photos de la soirée, stp ? :)

Answer (score 0):

En tant qu'antonyme du néologisme *identiqueter*, j'aurais dit **anonimer / anonymiser** en fonction de si l'action est réversible ou non.

> Rendre anonyme de manière réversible. Par exemple on **anonymise** une
>   copie d'un élève. Le procédé doit être réversible afin d'associer la
>   note de la copie avec le nom de l'élève. A l'inverse **anonymer** consiste
>   à rendre anonyme de manière définitive. Par exemple on anonyme les
>   données informatiques d'un logiciel dans le cadre d'une démonstration.

[Source](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/anonymiser)